# cucumber event handlers attached via registerHandler are now passed the associated object instead of an

Tags: angularjs, protractor, e2e-testing, cucumberjs, webdriverjs

I upgraded my cucumber to the following:

```
cucumberjs --version 1.2.2
protractor --version 4.0.1
Both installed globally via npm
```

And I noticed this message popping up:

---

> cucumber event handlers attached via registerHandler are now passed
>   the associated object instead of an event getPayloadItem will be
>   removed in the next major release

---

It also duplicates the @featureName and it always PASSES the test when logging in even when I purposely login with the WRONG login credentials.

```
 Given I am logged in as "username" with password "password"

1 scenario (1 passed)
1 step (1 passed)
0m04.067s
```

I was having issues earlier with ***passing in a callback*** and ***returning a promise***; but I removed the callback and stuck to only returning a promise and that got my tests to run and log me in at least;

However, this time, it always reports the test as PASSING even when it's failing; any idea ?

Comment: How are you doing your assertion (ie. can you paste the code that should fail when you have a wrong password)?